Navicat 16 Backup Error: 'column d.datlastsysoid does not exist' for Postgres 15.4 Database
I am using Navicat 16 to back up my remote PostgreSQL database, which is running version 15.4. However, during the backup process, I encounter an error that reads:
[ERR] ERROR:  column d.datlastsysoid does not exist
LINE 1: ...proargtypes AS params, p.proacl AS acl, (p.oid <= d.datlasts...

Here are the steps I followed before encountering this error:
Launched Navicat 16.
Connected to the remote PostgreSQL server.
Selected the database I want to back up.
Configured the backup settings as required.
Initiated the backup process.
The error occurred immediately after starting the backup. I've ensured that the connection details are correct and that I have the necessary permissions to perform the backup.
Could anyone provide insight into what might be causing this error or suggest a workaround?
Additional Information:
Navicat Version: 16
PostgreSQL Version: 15.4
Thank you in advance for any assistance!
I expected the backup process to complete successfully without any errors.
However, the error occurred immediately after starting the backup. I've ensured that the connection details are correct and that I have the necessary permissions to perform the backup.
Could anyone provide insight into what might be causing this error or suggest a workaround?

Use pg_dump or pg_dumpall to create a backup
